Tradingview advanced not showing
Working on integrating tradingview advanced on nextjs 14, but the chart is unable to show I've setup my trading widget by using the default parameters and trying other parameters but still unable to display chart
And not getting any errors on my console seem like all is fine but chart is not displaying
Below is the code block:
Dashboard.js:
import {ChartingLibraryWidgetOptions,ResolutionString} from '../../../public/static/charting_library/charting_library'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const defaultWidgetProps={
        symbol: "AAPL",
        interval: "1D",
        datafeedUrl: 'https://demo_feed.tradingview.com',
        library_path: "/static/charting_library/charting_library/",
        locale: "en",
        charts_storage_url: "*",
        charts_storage_api_version: "1.0",
        client_id: "https://ezfrx.com/",
        user_id: "https://ezfrx.com/",
        fullscreen: false,
        autosize: false,
        studiesOverrides: {},
        
      };


<div className='flex overflow-y-hidden justify-center items-center mt-4 lg:w-[100%] lg:h-[80%] max-lg:w-[100%] max-lg:h-[70%] md:w-[100%] md:h-[70%] max-md:h-[100%] sm:w-[100%] sm:h-[100%] max-sm:w-[100%] max-sm:h-[100%]  '>
   <Chart graph={graph} widget_data={defaultWidgetProps} />
</div>

Chart.js:

import { widget, version } from '../../public/static/charting_library/charting_library';
import '../../public/static/charting_library/datafeeds/udf/dist/bundle'


const chartContainerRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {

    console.log(props)
    const widgetOptions = {
      symbol: props.widget_data.symbol,
      // BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
      datafeed: new window.Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("https://demo_feed.tradingview.com"),
      interval: props.widget_data.interval,
      container: chartContainerRef.current,
      library_path: props.widget_data.libraryPath,

      locale: getLanguageFromURL() || 'en',
      disabled_features: ['header_widget'],
      enabled_features: ['study_templates'],
      charts_storage_url: props.widget_data.chartsStorageUrl,
      charts_storage_api_version: props.widget_data.chartsStorageApiVersion,
      client_id: props.widget_data.clientId,
      user_id: props.widget_data.userId,
      fullscreen: props.widget_data.fullscreen,
      autosize: props.widget_data.autosize,
      studies_overrides: props.widget_data.studiesOverrides,
      theme: 'light',
      timezone: 'Asia/Bangkok',
      debug:true,
      width:300,
      height:600
    };

    let tvWidget = new widget(widgetOptions);
    setTvwidget(tvWidget)
    
    tvWidget.onChartReady(() => {
      tvWidget.headerReady().then(() => {
        const button = tvWidget.createButton();
        button.setAttribute('title', 'Click to show a notification popup');
        button.classList.add('apply-common-tooltip');
        button.addEventListener('click', () => tvWidget.showNoticeDialog({
          title: 'Notification',
          body: 'TradingView Charting Library API works correctly',
          callback: () => {
            console.log('Noticed!');
          },
        }));

        button.innerHTML = 'Check API';
      });
    })

    if (tvWidget !== null) {
      tvWidget.remove();
      tvWidget = null;
    }

  }, [])

<div className={'p-0 lg:w-[100%] lg:h-[100vh] max-lg:w-[100%] max-lg:h-[100%] md:w-[100%] max-md:h-[100%] sm:h-[100%] max-sm:h-[100%] '}>
   <div ref={chartContainerRef} className='w-[100%] h-[100vh]'></div>
</div>


Can you share the whole component?

yes commented a more detailed component information
check the section

I updated your question and added the related components. You can remove your answer because it's not an answer, just an edit of the question

Seen the changes but the question is not resolved

Is the issue from the path or one of the widget object param is not correct?
